# the shadow that appears comes out of the container

Tags: flutter

I have a listview inside a container, but when i hover over the listTile, the shadow pops out of the container.
How can I solve the problem?[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) while asking question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This can cause the shadow to pop out of the container if the container
> has a fixed height and the ListTile extends beyond the container.

You may fix this problem by wrapping your ListView widget in a **Material** widget and set its elevation to the desired value.

**Code Example:**

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  child: Material(
    elevation: 4, // set the elevation value
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('List Item $index'),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```